# How to display a complex FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How would I display in the template a reactive form like this:

```
vertexEditorForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    vertices: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        type: [''],
        vertexA: [''],
        vectorA: this.fb.group({ x: [''], y: [''], z: [''] }),
        vertexB: [''],
        vectorB: this.fb.group({ x: [''], y: [''], z: [''] }),
      }),
    ]),
  });
```

I've got a getter for `vertices`

```
get vertices() {
    return this.vertexEditorForm.get('vertices') as FormArray;
  }
```

and then in my template I"m trying

```html
 <div formArrayName="vertices">
    <h3>Vertices</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let vertex of vertices.controls; let i = index">
      {{ i + 1 }}.
      <input
        id="vertex-{{ i }}"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Vertex"
        [formControlName]="type"
      />
    </div>

    <button type="button" (click)="addVertex()">+ Add Vertex</button>
  </div>
```

and I'm getting this error

```sh
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
    at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.mjs:1729:13)
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:1559:5)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:5280:9)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5836:43)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5781:18)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1506:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2543:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2502:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2453:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9499:21)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209:1)
    at zone.js:1321:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620:1)
```

Comment: `vertices` consists of array of FormGroups. You should be using `[formGroupName]="i"` for each item in ngFor loop and inside that item you will be able to use `formControlName="type"` etc

Comment: what @yurzui said, plus, it will take affect the same for the other groups you have there. s

Comment: Thanks @yurzui ! This actually worked! I'm struggling with the nested FormGroup and especially FormArray. Any ideas how I could go on about it?

Comment: As I said, its the same. You make a container with the formGroumName of vectorA for example and as children you add the formControlName of x, y, z for example